# Excel VBA timer performance differs depending on which sheet is active?

Tags: vba, excel, timer

I have a workbook with many sheets, each sheet has varying number of equations that inter-link with each other. I have a workbook wide VBA timer that is supposed to run every 5 seconds.

When I am active on a sheet that doesn't have a lot of formulas on it, it seems to run exactly once every 5 seconds... However, if I then change the active sheet to a more "busy" sheet, the vba timer just doesn't go off... Or if it does go off it was like minutes later. It is not until I switch to a less busy sheet again and then the timer runs magically like normal without having to reset anything.

I do not have any special VBA code specifically on the busy sheets... and I can't see why the VBA timer code won't run consistently across all sheets? If the timer is to be affected, it should be affected across ALL sheets and not only certain ones.

Here is the VBA timer code:

```
Sub TimerTick()

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    If toggletimer = True Then
        RunMyCode
        runWhen_ES = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
        Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=runWhen_ES, Procedure:="TimerTick", Schedule:=True
    End If
ErrorHandler:

End Sub
```

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing `RunMyCode`. If it causes the recalculation of the active sheet then of course your code will seem laggy if the active sheet has a massive amount of formulas.

Comment: The issue here is that I put a break point on the Sub TimerTick(). It isn't even entering that.

Comment: Well... is TimerTick in the worksheet open event? What is supposed to launch it in the first place?

Comment: No, the TimerTick code exists in the "Module" area of the Workbook. It is called by clicking on a button (on a sheet) that sets toggletimer to true, and then calls the TimerTick() subroutine:

Sub startTimer()
toggletimer = True
TimerTick()
End Sub

Comment: Another piece of crucial information is that other users do not have the same problem. This is happening on a specific computer. I have went over all Excel configurations and its all the same... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is Excel has a hard time running a macro and letting other processes run.  Add this after you specify your wait condition:

```
DoEvents
```

Excel will release the resources and threading used for running the macro instead of churning on it the whole time the wait is going on.  This should allow your spreadsheet to function normally between wait cycles.